# How to save typescript compiler errors in json file?

Tags: typescript, tsc, typescript-compiler-api

I want to save errors in json file format so I can parse those errors in language of my choice (ruby/python) to refactor my code.

I tried --pretty option but it did not gave output in json format

Answer (score 1):

There is **no** official compiler **option to format the errors** in **JSON** format. Here is the [Output Formatting Reference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#Output_Formatting_6256).

To export your errors into a file, you can use the `>`-Syntax:

```
tsc .\src\main.ts --pretty > errors.txt
```